# I'm using windows 8.1 and I've installed ubuntu as a dual boot but know I want to cancel ubuntu.How do I do that?

Tags: ubuntu

I'm using windows 8.1 and I've installed Ubuntu as a dual boot but now I want to cancel Ubuntu.How do I do that?

Comment: This question is off topic for SO. Better ask it on http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed ubuntu on a separate partition just go to disk management and format that partition.

If you used wubi to install ubuntu, then you can simply go to control panel > Add and remove programs > Uninstall ubuntu

Comment: Thanks so muck that was a lot of help